# Promise.All not return data when define multiple promises in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have an endpoint with mean.js that run multiple queries passed in an array, I want to run every query and return only one promise, I am using map to create each response and finally I want to response the result of all promises with promise.all.

```
var db = require(path.resolve('sequelize'));

exports.runQueries= function (req, res, queries) {

  // queries os an array

  var runQueries = function(query){
    return new Promise(resolve => db.sequelize.query(query, { type: db.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }));
  };

  var actions = queries.map(runQueries);

  Promise.all(actions).then(function(data){
    res.send(data);
  });

};
```

The problem is that each promises is in pending state and Promise.all().then never come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing `Promise` (the function). The callback it accepts is the one that accepts `resolve` and `reject` parameters. That callback's return value isn't used for anything. But you're treating it a bit like a `then` callback.

`db.sequelize.query` *already* returns a promise, you don't need to wrap it in another one, see `***` line:

```
var db = require(path.resolve('./config/lib/sequelize'));

exports.runQueries= function (req, res, queries) {

  // queries os an array

  var runQueries = function(query){
     // *** Just return the promise
    return db.sequelize.query(query, { type: db.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
  };

  var actions = queryFn.map(runQueries);

  Promise.all(actions).then(function(data){
    res.send(data);
  });

};
```

That can, of course, be much simpler:

```
var db = require(path.resolve('./config/lib/sequelize'));

exports.runQueries= function (req, res, queries) {

  // queries is an array

  var actions = queries(query => db.sequelize.query(query, { type: db.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }));

  Promise.all(actions).then(data => {
    res.send(data);
  });
};
```

---

Side note: `data` in the `Promise.all` callback will be an **array** of the results from `db.sequelize.query`'s various resolved promises. Are you sure you can just pass that array into `res.send()` directly?

Comment: Thank you @t-j-crowder, this work perfect, only aditional thing, every response is returned as array of objects, in the end I am getting one array of arrays, how I can get only one array with all element of arrays of every response?

Comment: @Resc6356: Search SO for how to create a single array from an array of arrays ("concat" and "flatten" might be a couple of useful search terms), it's covered here somewhere...